# Printing array of chars using pointer to char.

Tags: c++, char

In main.cpp I must print my char array like this:

```
const char *str(CValue::TestStringValue0());
cout << ' ' << *str << endl; //must not change
```

I can't modify this! So I need to print my array of char, but nor first value of array.

TestStringValue look like this..

```
static const char* TestStringValue0() {...}
```

Comment: Don't understand the question

Comment: Can you show the code for `TestStringValue0()`? Instead of returning e.g. `str` you would return `str+1`

Comment: What does `CValue::TestStringValue0` look like?  And what is your question?

Comment: Now I'm having it:

    static const char* TestStringValue0()
  '{
   return "0,0,0";
  }'
I must print "0,0,0", not "0"

Comment: Are you asking how to make code that prints a single character magically print a string without changing it? There's no sensible way to do that, and probably no crazy way either. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Cout <<*c;
How can I declare c, to print "0,0,0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if you're not supposed to modify this line:

```
cout << ' ' << *str << endl; //must not change
```

Then you can do like this:

```
const char *tempStr(CValue::TestStringValue0());
const char **str = &tempStr;
cout << ' ' << *str << endl; //must not change
```

In this case cout will print the whole string returned from TestStringValue0, while in the original code it printed only the first char.

P.S. What a strange condition you have :)

Comment: Why do you need a temporary variable?

Comment: @andre, since we can't modify the line with `count`, we need to make `*str* a pointer, so we need `str` to be a pointer to a pointer. As for the additional variable, I guess, I could avoid it, but I don't feel comfortable with getting address of values just returned from a function :) It's a matter of habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *str(CValue::TestStringValue0());
const char *p = str;

for ( ; *str; ++str )
{
    cout << ' ' << *str << endl; //must not change
}
```

:)